# CUPS doesn't work

Tags: printing, cups

As the title says I'm having problems with CUPS on my RPi when printing things to paper.

The way I have tried is by running `lp /home/pi/Desktop/python/car.py` with the default printer already set.

When i run that however i get this: `request id is UglyBrother-11 (1 file(s))` and nothing prints.

What is very interesting is if i try `sudo lp /home/pi/Desktop/python/car.py` I get the error:

`lp: Error - no default destination available.`

I know that this is a valid filename and I can otherwise edit, view and run it.

I've tried a pi zero, Two and Three all running the latest version of Raspbian with CUPS installed (`sudo apt-get install cups`) and none have worked.

Comment: Please add more information, your Pi model, Wheezy or Jeesie (or other), the program you're using to print, anything that you think it could be usefull to describe your problem.

Comment: To start, I don't think you have a printer connected physically to your RPi, then you will need to install CUSP (Common Unix Printing System) and define/connect your external 'remote' printer (via TCP/IP).

Comment: OK where can i download it? or what command ro run?

Comment: what kind of printer do you have? can it print the CUPS test page?

Comment: @scruss this problem has been fixed, I'm trying to find the tutorial I used to post an anwser but I remember it involved adding myself to the `lpadmin` group.